Non-metric gravity calculations
According to "Gravity and Strings" by T. Ortin (2015), the non-metricity tensor is calculated as
$$
Q_{\rho\mu\nu}\equiv\nabla_\rho g_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}-\Gamma^\beta_{\rho\mu}g_{\beta\nu}-\Gamma^\beta_{\rho\nu}g_{\mu\beta}
$$
where $\Gamma^\beta_{\rho\nu}$ is the extended affine connection defined as
$$
\Gamma_{\mu \nu}{ }^\rho=\left\{\begin{array}{c}
\rho \\
\mu \nu
\end{array}\right\}+K_{\mu \nu}{ }^\rho+L_{\mu \nu}{ }^\rho.
$$
The first term is the usual Levi-Civita connection. The second and third term are the contortion and distortion tensors, respectively. The constortion tensor is defined as:
$$
K_{\mu \nu}{}^\rho=\frac{1}{2} g^{\rho \sigma}\left\{T_{\mu \sigma \nu}+T_{\nu \sigma \mu}-T_{\mu \nu \sigma}\right\}
$$
and the distortion tensor
$$
L_{\mu \nu}{ }^\rho=\frac{1}{2}\left\{Q_{\mu \nu}{ }^\rho+Q_{\nu \mu}{ }^\rho-Q^\rho{ }_{\mu \nu}\right\}.
$$
As it can be seen, the contorsion tensor depends on the torsion tensor which depends on the extended connection as $$T_{\mu \nu}{ }^\rho=-2 \Gamma_{[\mu \nu]}{ }^\rho,$$ and the distortion tensor depends explicitly on the non-metricity tensor $Q$. But in order to calculate the $Q$ tensor, the connection $\Gamma$ is needed and for the latter the $Q$ tensor is needed as it can be seen from the $L$ tensor. Are there other ways to compute the $Q$ tensor or am I misunderstanding the given definitions?

I imagine it depends on the context, but assume you had an explicit form for the connection $\Gamma$, metric $g$ and metric derivatives (so you know the Levi Civita connection). You can compute $T$ directly from $\Gamma$ using the definition of $T$. Then you can compute $L$ by solving the decomposition of $\Gamma$ into Levi-Civita connection + $K(T)$ + $L$. Then you can compute $Q$ by inverting your last formula. Alternatively, with the same assumption you know $\Gamma$, $g$, and $\partial g$, you could compute $Q$ directly from your first formula and then compute $L$ from your last formula.

So, I guess, with at least some assumption of what data is given (ie, assuming you know $\Gamma$, $g$, and $\partial g$), there are multiple routes to compute $Q$. In practice I don't know what information you're likely to have and what you need to calculate, but I would guess there's some equation of motion that you solve for $\Gamma$ in terms of metric and matter fields, and another equation for the metric, (like in the Palatini formalism for GR), so that's why I'm assuming you know this information.

@Andrew what if the only data that I have is the metric but no explicit form of $\Gamma$ ? But I see that only the Levi-Civita connection can be obtain directly from the metric and it's derivatives. The problem is the other components of $\Gamma$
